# Node.js if statement after if statement

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to get my app to process an if statement only if it matched the last if statement used.  The workflow should be like this.

```
if(
  (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
    && (req.method === 'POST') && (req.body.pin === '1234')
) {Do step 1}
```

If pin matches above make this next if statement possible.

```
if(
            (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
            && (req.method === 'PUT')
        ) {do modified step 2}
```

How would I write this up?

All other requests using a different pin, would not use the modified step 2 and would be like follows

```
if(
      (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
        && (req.method === 'POST'))
    ) {Do step 1}
```

If pin doesn't match

```
if(
            (req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
            && (req.method === 'PUT')
        ) {normal step 2}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put one if statement inside the other one?

Comment: Pretty much yes. Is it possible? Maybe a way to do a then statement? If the first if statement gets used then if the send step matches, it will proceed with the new step